# Google colab cache google drive content

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset on google drive that's about 20GB big.
I use a generator to pull in the dataset to my keras/TF models, and the overhead of loading the files (for every batch) is insane.

I want to prefetch the content as one operation and then simply fetched from the local VM disk

I tried this:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!mkdir -p $RAW_NOTEBOOKS_DIR
!cp $RAW_NOTEBOOKS_DIR $LOCAL_NOTEBOOKS_DIR
```

However, this snippet runs finishes executing instantly (so it obviously didn't download the data - which was the intent of the `cp` command (copying from Drive to local).

Is this at all possible?

---

```py
RAW_NOTEBOOKS_DIR = "/content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks"
```

Comment: Did you check if the invocation of `cp` is failing? `cp` can't copy directories without the `-r` flag.

Comment: @Brian I actually noticed I get an issue with the spaces in the google drive paths. Should `...\My\ Drive\...` work to fetch within the `My Drive` folder?

Comment: @Brian problems also related to: `ValueError: Mountpoint must not contain a space.` when I tried to do `drive.mount(RAW_NOTEBOOKS_DIR)`

Comment: `RAW_NOTEBOOKS_DIR = "/content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks"`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a good example on google codelab for doing this, they write the dataset in a local TFRecords:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/keras-flowers-tpu/#0

you can find more info here:

https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/tfrecord/

so instead of reading the data every time from google drive you just need to read it one time and write it in the local memory in a TFRecord, then pass it to the model for training.

If you follow the guides is pretty straightforward.